# <gripper> tag (gazebo::physics::Gripper) doesn't create the fixed joint between the gripper and the object within it

Tags: ros, gazebo-1.9, gazebo-plugin

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

I have been trying to use the `<gripper>` tag in my urdf robot like this:

```
<gazebo>
    <gripper name="grasping">
        <grasp_check>
            <attach_steps>20</attach_steps>
            <detach_steps>40</detach_steps>
            <min_contact_count>1</min_contact_count>
        </grasp_check>
        <gripper_link>r_finger_link</gripper_link>
        <gripper_link>l_finger_link</gripper_link>
        <palm_link>gripper_base</palm_link>
    </gripper>
</gazebo>
```

I have checked the corresponding [code](https://bitbucket.org/osrf/gazebo/src/66f62831c3dfe933750815cb96dc04d21ec2a261/gazebo/physics/Gripper.cc) and it's loaded properly. The problem is that the [Gripper::OnContact](https://bitbucket.org/osrf/gazebo/src/66f62831c3dfe933750815cb96dc04d21ec2a261/gazebo/physics/Gripper.cc?at=gazebo_1.9#cl-212) function is never called, therefore **the fixed joint between the gripper and the object within the gripper will never be created**.

The contacts do exist as can be seen in the figure. Additionally when I use a `ContactSensor` like the `libgazebo_ros_bumper.so` plugin I also detect such contacts.

Has somebody run with the same problem?

I'm working with **gazebo-1.9.1**, **ros-groovy** and **gazebo_ros_pkg**

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/4324/%3Cgripper%3E-tag-(gazebo::physics::gripper)-doesn%27t-create-the-fixed-joint-between-the-gripper-and-the-object-within-it/) by [Francisco](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/314/francisco/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 143 on 2013-09-13

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Can you give this pull-request a try:

https://bitbucket.org/osrf/gazebo/pull-request/713/fixed-gripper-and-added-test/diff

---

Originally posted by [nkoenig](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/5/nkoenig/) with karma: 7676 on 2013-09-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Francisco](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/314/francisco/) on 2013-09-19**:
Thanks Nate! That works, although it takes a while (~ 5 sec.) to attach and detach the object. I guess it's a matter of playing with the `attach_steps` and `detach_steps` and maybe to relax the [attach condition](https://bitbucket.org/osrf/gazebo/src/3bbcac98c776a6ac3545d21a299a1786b35c22ca/gazebo/physics/Gripper.cc#cl-208)